# Yodlee soap service How to get accountNumber and routingNumber from getItemSummaries method

Tags: soap, yodlee

I'm integrating yodlee soap service to loan management system. To perform validation I need to get accountNumber and routingNumber from the bank account. On my bank account web site I can see account number but yodlee masks out part of account numbers by 'x' symbol and returns something like xxxx7-50 in getItemSummaries response. Also some accounts have empty routing number.

Is that some king of security limitation or it can be due to fact that I'm currently using test yodlee account? 
Is there way to get bank routing number and original bank account number without masking by using soap yodlee service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of security limitation of the Aggregation product.If you wish to have unmasked account number then you will have to go through some tests from Yodlee's security team and then Yodlee can customize the API to send you unmasked account number. For this you need to get in touch with sales representative.

Also if you are building the solution for US market then you can try out the [IAV](https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API) data service APIs , if you are interested in Account number and routing number. As IAV is the main product for verification of account.